# Where should I ask about VBA Digital Certificates and Saving a MS Word document?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the correct site for this type of question or not so I thought I'd check here for a Site-Recommendation before asking.

### Example Question

> If a MS Word document requires a Digital Certificate to make use of VBA, how would I have the document `SaveAs` without losing its Digital Certificate?
>
> My document currently makes use of `SaveAs` on three (3) separate occasions in its lifespan.

### Overview

Basically, I created some UserForms in MS Word and applied some VBA automation to them. My workplace then applied changes to their policy regarding Macro enabled files to now require a Digital Certificate. If there is no Digital Certificate, Macros are disabled (and cannot be enabled).

I would like to find out some information about, and seek some suggestions about what to do if the document requires saving after the Digital Certificate has been applied as to my understanding the Digital Certificates will be removed from the document once the document is saved.

**NOTE:**

- I **don't** need to know about how to get a Digital Certificate.
- I'm looking to find out about how they work with MS Word (as the web seems to refer to Excel mostly and I'm not sure if there are any differences).
- I'm trying to work out if there are any ways to keep my current development with minimal changes to work without losing the Digital Certificate.
- If required, I'd be looking for some suggestions/advice on an approach to work around the 'Save' issue with dropping the Certificate (which I understand may not be an appropriate request for some sites on SE).

Most importantly, **discussing this with my work is not an option for me** (strange I know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [Super User](https://superuser.com/):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> computer hardware,
>   computer software, or
>   personal and home computer networking

Comment: As a super user mod. Ya... this seems right. I'd have posted this answer if I was a little quicker ;)